# Can we apply for UAE-based credit cards based on non-resident bank accounts in UAE?

Tags: payment-cards, uae

Can we apply for UAE-based credit cards based on non-resident bank accounts in UAE?

Comment: Do you actually need/want a **credit** card, or is just any payment card fine? Usually credit card issuers don’t want to issue cards to non-residents because it makes it substantially harder to go after you if you fail to pay. That can sometimes be mitigated with a guarantee of some sort (which really makes it a debit card). But terms vary a lot, check the fine print and eventually try to apply for one, you’ll see.

Comment: Need a credit card as UAE banks have good offers on lounge access.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought..it's difficult to score a credit card

Comment: Are you really only wanting lounge offers? Instead of going the CC route, just get [Priority Pass](https://www.prioritypass.com/)

Comment: What did the credit card issuer say when you asked them?

Comment: Awaiting reply from them but I don't expect much @mlc

Comment: @NicolasFormichella that's the last option. trying to minimize cost